# Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a onClick event in react:

```
onClick={this.selectedComponent}
```

and below is selectedComponent:

```
selectedComponent = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            component: e.target.name,
        });
    };
```

This works fine. But when I am trying to pass two functions inside my onClick event then I get an error as `Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`

Below is how I am trying to pass two functions inside my onClick:

```
onClick={(event) => { this.changeColor("activeProfile"); this.selectedComponent();}}
```

Individually both the functions works, but when I combine them, then I am getting the above mentioned error. Is the way I am passing two functions inside onClick is not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the event to your function call.

Change this:

```
onClick={(event) => { this.changeColor("activeProfile"); this.selectedComponent();}}
```

To this:

```
onClick={(event) => { this.changeColor("activeProfile"); this.selectedComponent(event);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in event to your selected component like below:

```
onClick={(event) => { this.changeColor("activeProfile"); this.selectedComponent(event);}}
```